# listview in a fragment jumping to other activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Should there be an alternative for it?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: You are missing the Code for your `OnItemClickListener`, please add it.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, the lines you enclosed with ** should be inside a method.

Comment: Perhaps we could help you but you have absolutely nothing of any substance in your post. You are missing your item click listener, you are missing your logcat output (if there is any, couldn't tell by the ambiguity in the post). Add in some more details to get an anwer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

        switch(position)
        case 0:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), OneActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
            break;
        case 1:
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);
             getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
             break;            

  }
});
```